# Same session folder for multible PHP installations?

Tags: php, session

Can I set multible PHP installations to use the same session folder? Or will they conflict and overwrite each others session files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the default session save handler in PHP you can share their save location and it will not conflict or overwrite each other, but note the side effects:

Since the default session save handler in PHP determines which sessions exists (and alive) by checking the files in the save location, the different PHP installations will **share** their sessions if you choose this solution. This is somewhat you probably don't want in a production environment.